# sqlalchemy group_by got extra condition than provided condition

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy with Python handle query some MySQL, the problem is that when i tried to execute the query in normal SQL management tool (in my case is `Navicat`), it worked completely fine (only 49k records and do not have any duplicate value after group by the condition I want)

```
select q1.*, cr.psubject_code, fs.num_of_credit as NOC, sum(cr.grade * fs.num_of_credit) as total_grade, sum(fs.num_of_credit) as total_NOC, sum(cr.grade * fs.num_of_credit)/sum(fs.num_of_credit) as average_grade
from 
(select fg.id as group_id, fg.pterm_id as term_id, fg.pterm_name as term_name, fg.psubject_name as subject_name,
fgm.member_login
from fu_group fg
join fu_group_member fgm on fg.id = fgm.groupid
where fg.pterm_id >= 24 and fg.is_virtual = 0) q1 JOIN t7_course_result cr on (cr.groupid = q1.group_id and q1.member_login = cr.student_login) join fu_subject fs on cr.psubject_code = fs.subject_code
where cr.val = 1
group by q1.member_login
```

But when I convert to the `SQLALchemy ORM` code in Python, it will work until the where clause `cr.val = 1`, and got duplicate value when try to group_by the `q1.member_login`. I had test and discover that if I group by the id, it would work just fine with the same result in normal SQL, but when I group by some attribute with type of `VARCHAR`, it will not only group by the condition I put in, but also by its own condition for specific record.

```
async def avg_grade(engine, partitioner, mod_number):
    q1 = select(
        fu_group.id,
        fu_group.pterm_id,
        fu_group_member.member_login,
        fu_group.pterm_name
    ).join_from(
        fu_group_member,
        fu_group,
        fu_group.id == fu_group_member.groupid
    ).where(
        fu_group.pterm_id >= 24,
        fu_group.is_virtual == 0,
    ).subquery()
    q = select(
        q1.c.id,
        q1.c.pterm_id,
        q1.c.member_login,
        q1.c.pterm_name,
        t7_course_result.psubject_code,
        func.sum(t7_course_result.grade * fu_subject.num_of_credit),
        func.sum(fu_subject.num_of_credit),
        cast(func.sum(t7_course_result.grade * fu_subject.num_of_credit)/func.sum(fu_subject.num_of_credit), DECIMAL(10, 1))
    ).join_from(
        q1,
        t7_course_result,
        and_(
            q1.c.id == t7_course_result.groupid,
            q1.c.member_login == t7_course_result.student_login)
    ).join_from(
        t7_course_result,
        fu_subject,
        t7_course_result.psubject_code == fu_subject.subject_code
    ).where(
        t7_course_result.val == 1,
        q1.c.id % 17 == mod_number
    ).group_by(
        q1.c.member_login)
```

This leading to the result instead of only distinct member_login, it will duplicate the `member_login` value but with different key that I did not mention in the `group_by()` clause.

Can someone give any idea why this happen? Is this a bug from `SQLAlchemy`?

The class defined for `ORM`:

```
class fu_group(Base):
    __tablename__= 'fu_group'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    pterm_id = Column(Integer, index=True)
    pterm_name = Column(VARCHAR, index=True)
    is_virtual = Column(SmallInteger, index=True)
    psubject_name = Column(VARCHAR, index=True)

class fu_group_member(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'fu_group_member'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    groupid = Column(BigInteger, index=True)
    member_login = Column(VARCHAR, index=True)

class t7_course_result(Base):
    __tablename__ = 't7_course_result'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    groupid = Column(BigInteger, index=True)
    student_login = Column(VARCHAR, index=True)
    val = Column(VARCHAR, index=True)
    grade = Column(DECIMAL(10, 1), index=True)
    psubject_code = Column(VARCHAR(25), index=True)

class fu_subject(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'fu_subject'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    department_id = Column(Integer, index=True)
    subject_code = Column(VARCHAR(25), index=True)
    num_of_credit = Column(Integer, index=True)
```

Not sure this affect much!

Comment: There's a lot going on in that query - can you reduce it to a [mre] (with emphasis on _minimal_) with some sample data that will reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have at least this join swapped, you have `join_from(fu_group_member, fu_group)` but your original query was `FROM fu_group fg JOIN fu_group_member`.  I think you want `join_from(fu_group, fu_group_member, ...)` to match that.

Comment: i will check for it, thank you sir